# How to implement child nested document using solr and spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, solr, nested

I have a sample nested child document as below

```
[   
    {
      "id": 100,
      "fieldName": "fld-100",
      "description": "description",
      "icon": "icon-1",
      "items": [
        {
          "id": "1",
          "name": "item-1"
        },
        {
          "id": "2",
          "name": "item-2"
        }
      ],
      "relations": [
        {
          "id": "1",
          "relType": "Type1",
          "fldName": "fld-1"
        },
        {
          "id": "2",
          "relType": "Type2",
          "fldName": "fld-2"
        }
      ],
      "userInteractions": [
        {
          "id": "1",
          "interactionType": "tagging",
          "interactionContent": ["test","test2"],
          "createTS": "2021-01-14",
          "updateTS": "2021-01-14"
        }
      ],
      "reviewNumbers": {
        "id": "1_888",
        "numberOfComments": 1,
        "numberOfStarRating": 5
      },
      "tags": ["test","test2"]
    }
]
```

Below is the managed-schema which I created in solr:

```
<field name="_root_" type="string" docValues="false" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="id" type="string" multiValued="false" indexed="true" required="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="description" type="string"/>
<field name="fieldName" type="string" uninvertible="true" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="icon" type="string"/>
<field name="tags" type="string" uninvertible="true" multiValued="true" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="items" type="_nest_path_">
    <field name="name" type="string" uninvertible="true" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
</field> 
<field name="relations" type="_nest_path_">
    <field name="fldName" type="string" uninvertible="true" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
    <field name="relType" type="string" uninvertible="true" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
</field> 
<field name="reviewNumbers" type="_nest_path_">
    <field name="averageStarRating" type="string" uninvertible="true" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
    <field name="numberOfComments" type="string" uninvertible="true" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
    <field name="numberOfStarRating" type="string" uninvertible="true" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
</field>
<field name="userInteractions" type="_nest_path_">
    <field name="interactionContent" type="strings" uninvertible="true" multiValued="true" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
    <field name="interactionType" type="string" uninvertible="true" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
    <field name="createTS" type="string" uninvertible="true" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
    <field name="updateTS" type="string" uninvertible="true" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
</field>
```

When I try to save, the parent and child documents are getting flattened and saved as individual document with just *root* field having the association to parent. The same if I try to get by Id from spring boot solr application, I get just the parent document (child documents are null).

Am I missing something? Is there any github nested structure example which I can refer?

Answer (score 0):

I , i have a similar issue , we are working with solr 8.11 and spring boot , when insert the document in solr there is no problem, but at the moment of query , the document is flattened  and there isn't a parent/child association .We are surfer a lot on forums and the poor documentation with no luck . It seems that the spring data solr doest'n support this kind of opperation

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("60873744ff974f7d24db1941"),
"docType" : "PARENT",
"idUser" : 9075280,
"situacionLaboral" : "SIN_TRABAJO",
"aniosExperienciaLaboral" : 0,
"tieneVehiculo" : false,
"tieneLicenciaConducir" : false,
"descripcionNacionalidad" : "Cubana",
"numeroDocumentoIdentidad" : "91013007224",
"educacion" : [ 
    {
        "_id" : NumberLong(936264693890170882),
        "docType" : "EDUCACION",
        "nivelEstudio" : "SECUNDARIA",
        "anioEgreso" : 2015,
        "aniosEstudios" : 0,
        "situacionActual" : "EGRESADO",
        "descripcionRegion" : "Extranjero",
        "descripcionInstitucion" : "UCI ",
        "modoEstudio" : "PRESENCIAL",

    }
],
"idiomas" : [
    {
        "id" : 936264731181727747,
        "docType" : "IDIOMAS",
        "idIdioma" : 1,
        "descripcionIdioma" : "Inglés",
        "lenguajeNativo" : false,
        "nivel" : "MEDIO"
    }
         {
        "id" : 936264731181727742,
        "docType" : "IDIOMAS",
        "idIdioma" : 1,
        "descripcionIdioma" : "Frances",
        "lenguajeNativo" : false,
        "nivel" : "MEDIO"
    }
]
```

}